# Xero API error Uncertified app connection limit reached

Tags: postman, xero-api

We are developing a few things that has some api work with Xero connections.  When i try to authenticate xero account through Postman the organization selection says "Uncertified app connections limitreached.  You can only connect two uncertified apps to an organization."

Here i have two questions.
1- What is the definition of uncertified app for Xero.
2- Is there a place where i can see those uncertified apps?

Response is highly appreciated.

don't know what to do to get it corrected.

Answer (score 0):

1. An uncertified app is any app created that hasn't gone through Xero's lengthy [app certification process](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/xero-app-store/app-partner-guides/app-partner-steps).
2. You can see the apps you have built in your account [HERE](https://developer.xero.com/app/manage).